# docker container connect volume to remote server with ssh keys

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-volume, sshfs

I have been working with Docker recently and I am new to docker and I have managed to setup containers for nginx/php and mysql.

I have assets of the website which are on a seperate server and I have connected to the same using sshfs and i am able transfer files between container folder and remote folder.
But this is done using the password and now I need to connect using ssh key.

Below is the example of docker-compose file

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./images/fpm
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ../<code_base>/:/var/www/html
      - sshfs_test:/var/www/html/public/assets

volumes:
  sshfs_test:
    name: "sshfs_test"
    driver: vieux/sshfs:latest
    driver_opts:
      sshcmd: "<server_user>@<server_ip>:/path/to/assets"
      password: "<my_password>"
      allow_other: ""
```

This above example works but I need to connect using ssh private key instead of password.

Answer (score 0):

Look at : https://github.com/vieux/docker-volume-sshfs/issues/19#issuecomment-748609520

Finally found the correct way to make it happen on my system (one rpi as a server, one mac hosting the remote volume), thanks to this do not have to have to share my password.

1. installing vieux/sshfs with make all (as @ogmundur recommended ON ALL MACHINES, for me : rpi (where my server is) and mac (to put my volume shared)
2. be sure to have a root keygene already done (for me : in Pi), and identify the folder where rsa are : /root/.ssh/, ensure the public key has been shared (for me with : mac), otherwise have a look at : https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/passwordless.md)
3. (for me on pi) `docker plugin disable vieux/sshfs:next`
4. (for me on pi) `docker plugin set vieux/sshfs sshkey.source=/root/.ssh/` (see this : https://blog.raphaelpiccolo.com/post/850)
5. (for me on pi) `docker plugin enable vieux/sshfs:next`
6. (for me on pi) and this is my `docker-compose.yml` to be launched :

   ```
   version: "3"

   services:
     myserver:
       image: nginx:latest
       ports:
         - "80:80"
       volumes:
         - COMMONVOLUME:/usr/share/nginx/html

     volumes:
       COMMONVOLUME:
         driver: "vieux/sshfs:next"
         driver_opts:
           sshcmd: @:/REMOTEPATH/WHERE/THE/FOLDER/TOBESYNCFORVOLUME/IS
           allow_other: ""
   ```

Comment: Please take a moment to learn how to properly format lists and code samples in your StackOverflow posts. I've fixed the formatting in this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Larsks, I'll do it

Comment: i didnt notice i got referenced here thanks :) i have to tell that i updated the blog post recently to clarify that this module works, but i had 2 major total data loss using this module (once a year). And i cant understand what caused that. it must be unstable and therefore not used in production.
once in a while "docker volume rm xxx" cause all data to be deleted on the the remote server...